# SQL Agrupando por nome, data e quantidade por mês

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Não estou conseguindo agrupar esse resultando por mês(CAMPO "PP.PAPELETA_DATA"). Tipo a quantidade (count(PD.PessoaId) as Total) separado por mês! Alguém poderia me dar um help?
Uso SQL SERVER 2012.

```
SELECT 
PE2.PessoaNome,
count(PD.PessoaId) as Total
FROM PAPELETA PP
INNER JOIN PESSOASDETALHE PD ON PP.PAPELETA_PESS = PD.PessoaId
INNER JOIN PESSOAS PE ON PD.AnalistaId = PE.PessoaId
INNER JOIN PESSOAS PE2 ON PP.PAPELETA_PESS = PE2.PessoaId
GROUP BY PE2.PessoaNome
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Este relatório sempre mostrará um período de 3 meses? Ou o intervalo será informado pelo Cliente, assim gerando N colunas? Caso você precise de Novo colunas, você terá de trucar a data antes de agrupar, e depois usar um cursor para montar uma query a ser executada pelo sp_executesql.

Comment: Como é a estrutura da sua tabela?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função interna *[MONTH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187813(v=sql.110).aspx)*, que retorna qual o mês do parâmetro informado, que deve ser um *time*, *date*, *smalldatetime*, *datetime*, *datetime2* ou *datetimeoffset*, conforme consta na documentação da função. Em conjunto com o *MONTH*, você também pode utilizar o *[CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms181765(v=sql.110).aspx)* e *[SUM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187810(v=sql.110).aspx)* para verificar se a data é de um mês específico, se for você soma mais um, caso contrário desconsidera, algo assim:

```
SELECT 
    PE2.PessoaNome,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (MONTH(PP.PAPELETA_DATA) = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Qtd_Jan,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (MONTH(PP.PAPELETA_DATA) = 2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Qtd_Fev,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (MONTH(PP.PAPELETA_DATA) = 3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Qtd_Mar,
FROM 
    PAPELETA PP
    INNER JOIN PESSOASDETALHE PD ON PP.PAPELETA_PESS = PD.PessoaId
    INNER JOIN PESSOAS PE ON PD.AnalistaId = PE.PessoaId
    INNER JOIN PESSOAS PE2 ON PP.PAPELETA_PESS = PE2.PessoaId
GROUP BY 
    PE2.PessoaNome
```

> **Nota:** não tenho o SQL SERVER para testar no momento, mas a lógica é essa, caso apresente algum problema, deixe um comentário na resposta que corrijo assim que possível.

Comment: A sua consulta pode juntar meses de anos diferentes, o que pode ser indesejado.

Comment: Porque o downvote nessa resposta? Ela apresenta uma elegante solução para a pergunta. Para resolver o problema do ano, basta incluí-lo como mais uma coluna e agrupá-lo ou então restringí-lo na cláusula where. Existe só um problema de sintaxe, já que deve-se fechar o CASE com END.

Comment: Realmente @gmsantos, porém a minha resposta foi só um ponto de partida, e na pergunta não fica claro que é necessário considerar o ano, então "pode ser indesejado" é algo relativo.

Answer (score 1):

Você necessita agrupar pela data também.

Lembre-se de excluir os dias da data PAPELETA_DATA, senão você terá os dados agrupados pelos dias. Este é o motivo de utilizar as functions **MONTH** e **YEAR**. Fica mais ou menos assim a sua consulta:

```
SELECT PE2.PessoaNome       
     , 'Qtd-' + CONVERT(CHAR(2), MONTH(PP.PAPELETA_DATA)) + '-' + CONVERT(CHAR(4),     YEAR(PP.PAPELETA_DATA)) AS Periodo
     , COUNT(PD.PessoaId) AS Total
  FROM PAPELETA            PP
 INNER JOIN PESSOASDETALHE PD ON PP.PAPELETA_PESS   = PD.PessoaId
 INNER JOIN PESSOAS        PE ON PD.AnalistaId      = PE.PessoaId
 INNER JOIN PESSOAS       PE2 ON PP.PAPELETA_PESS   = PE2.PessoaId
 GROUP BY PE2.PessoaNome
        , MONTH(PP.PAPELETA_DATA)
        , YEAR(PP.PAPELETA_DATA)
```

Answer (score -1):

`SELECT 
MONTH(PP.PAPELETA_DATA) as mes, count(*)  as Qtd
FROM 
PAPELETA PP
GROUP BY (MONTH(PP.PAPELETA_DATA))`